# Aws codebuild, all builds failing

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

I'm having an issue with AWS codebuild.  My setup has worked for the last year with no issue. Last night all my builds started failing.

Log below.

As far as I can see, this is failing before it even gets to my docker file so I have no control over installing the required key before doing the apt update. It does the same thing no matter which AWS build environment i specify.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:08:31 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:08:32 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src499283105/src/github.com/TeamTizo/Tizohub
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src499283105/src/github.com/TeamTizo/Tizohub/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for Github and GitHub Enterprise sources
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for Github and GitHub Enterprise sources
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for Github and GitHub Enterprise sources
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:01 No runtime version selected in buildspec.
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src499283105/src/github.com/TeamTizo/Tizohub
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Configuring ssm agent with target id: codebuild:a8fabfec-8d23-4369-bfcd-40ebd15907f6
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Successfully updated ssm agent configuration
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Registering with agent
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Phases found in YAML: 4
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03  INSTALL: 3 commands
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03  PRE_BUILD: 9 commands
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03  BUILD: 3 commands
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03  POST_BUILD: 3 commands
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Running command ls -alt
total 272
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     21 Jan 25 11:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root    147 Jan 25 11:09 writable
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Jan 25 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root root   4096 Jan 25 11:09 system
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    384 Jan 25 11:09 th_env.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    173 Jan 25 11:09 public
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2236 Jan 25 11:09 spark
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3895 Jan 25 11:08 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2061 Jan 25 11:08 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root   4096 Jan 25 11:08 modules
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 Jan 25 11:08 error.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1870 Jan 25 11:08 buildspec.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1861 Jan 25 11:08 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 222990 Jan 25 11:08 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     20 Jan 25 11:08 devops
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root    248 Jan 25 11:08 app
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     36 Jan 25 11:08 build
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    684 Jan 25 11:08 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2038 Jan 25 11:08 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1159 Jan 25 11:08 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     31 Jan 25 11:08 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     87 Jan 25 11:08 .git

[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:03 Running command apt update

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 https://apt.corretto.aws stable InRelease [10.7 kB]
Get:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:8 https://apt.corretto.aws stable/main amd64 Packages [11.8 kB]
Get:9 https://apt.corretto.aws stable/main i386 Packages [3514 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages [31.1 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages [990 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4732 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages [293 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [793 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [740 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [681 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [605 kB]
Get:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [2955 B]
Get:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [2960 B]
Err:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages [9385 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages [134 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages [36.7 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [1324 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1055 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [730 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages [31.5 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [705 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [8978 B]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [516 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1738 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [999 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7286 B]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages [5545 B]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [3520 B]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main i386 Packages [3479 B]
Reading package lists...
W: https://apt.corretto.aws/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
E: The repository 'https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease' is not signed.

[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:09 Command did not exit successfully apt update exit status 100
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:09 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/01/25 11:09:09 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: apt update. Reason: exit status 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it in privileged mode?
Codebuild->Edit->Environment->Override Image->Privileged mode

Answer (score 0):

There was a CodeBuild Ubuntu images issue which is now fixed. Refer [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/594).